# Function the_content not working

Tags: filters, the-content

I'm developing a site with the Advanced Custom Fields and SF Taxonomy Thumbnail.

In any page (post type = page), I'm with an error that I don't know what is happening:

[image: Error]

My custom template code: https://gist.github.com/gabfr/79e1c915d0b2f9ed6620aee7fdc8c8b0 (similar to the page.php)

I don't have custom filters in my function.php, and I already tried to deactivate the plugins. None of them worked.

Someone experienced this error before?

Comment: Never use page-{something}.php as a page template as it is a part of template heirarchy. Also use home_url() instead of bloginfo('url').

Comment: @bravokeyel thanks for the tips, still not working :(

Answer (score 2):

My error was on [line 21](https://gist.github.com/gabfr/79e1c915d0b2f9ed6620aee7fdc8c8b0#file-page-logistica-php-L21), the global variable `$pages` is used by the wordpress. Overwriting it on that line caused the error above.

Comment: Perhaps you could tell a little bit more how you tracked this down from `get_the_content` in `post-template.php`. Just a little lesson in bug tracking...

Comment: Here's a list of [reserved terms](https://codex.wordpress.org/Reserved_Terms) that could cause conflicts with core functionality too.

Comment: @cjbj I went to the root of the error (post-template.php file) and tried to understand the line of codes around the line of error. I saw the declaration of global variables at the top of the method.